# Android camera permissions reduce availability on Playstore

Tags: android, flutter, google-play, android-biometric-prompt, android-biometric

I have an flutter app in playstore but rigth now i'm trying to update with new features, but some camera permissions/features are reducing the app availability
The current devices admited are 17.706 and with my new update are just
12.672, and the permissions are marked as optional in AndroidManifest

[image]

And the playstore show this
[image]

[image]

Is other way to mark as optional or something i can do to avoid reduce availability of my app?

UPDATE 1
Some dependency is using this permission but i can't find which one, and i', trying to override in AndroidManifest, because when i upload my app the description is this

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Remove Extra permission for camera and ask only for one "CAMARA only"

Check out More Info Here : [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28500736/app-not-compatible-with-certain-devices)

Comment: The problem is some package that i don't know which is, are using this feature, and i'm trying to override that permisión and mark as non required

Comment: i have putted extra permission in my flutter project so that time I face this one but I don't have more idea for android native.

you can try it (remove extra permission if not needed ) and test on google play store